# I'm trying to repeat the same column, I only want to the workingDate to be altered

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to repeat everything except `workingdate`. The below code works, but I was wondering if there is way to make it work all at once instead of writing the date again and again.

```
insert into WorkingSchedule(
    employeeid,
    workingdate,
    DepartmentId,
    WorkingShiftIdForecast,
    WorkingShiftIdSEPE,
    WorkingShiftIdActual,
    notes,
    status,
    ActualStartTime1,
    ActualEndTime1,
    ActualStartTime2,
    ActualEndTime2,
    TimeAttendanceId
)
values (754, '2022-11-20', 6, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 10149)


Employeeid|Workingdate|DepartmentId|etc
--------------------------------------------
754       |2022-09-10 |     6      |etc 
754       |2022-09-11 |     6      |etc
```

Comment: No one can read those results. Posting images of technical information like sample like sample data or results, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I've seen here other than spam for a question to be downvoted and then closed or ignored.

Comment: Please read: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This poor person has to work Christmas Eve and Christmas Day :(

Comment: Well, what dates do you want it to be?...just the range your sample shows `12/07/2022` through `12/28/2022`?

Comment: Le'ts say to add dates  from 2022-01-01 to 2022-11-20. Sorry I couldn't upload it properly.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem? Did my answer help at all?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply guys, thanks for your answers, thank you Ann for providing me this solution too.

Comment: Hi, Alex.  If my answer helped, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.  Either way, congrats on solving your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a bunch of "boilerplate" records can be made much easier than executing `INSERT` after `INSERT`.

What you need is a list of the dates you want to insert records for, since that's the only thing that changes from record to record.  If you don't have one in the database, you can generate one on the fly, using a *recursive common table expression*.

Try this:

```
;
WITH A as (
  select Convert(Datetime, '1/1/2022') as workDate
  union all
  select DateAdd(d, 1, A.workDate) as workDate
  from   A
  where  A.workDate < '12/31/2022'
)
insert into WorkingSchedule(
    employeeid,
    workingdate,
    DepartmentId,
    WorkingShiftIdForecast,
    WorkingShiftIdSEPE,
    WorkingShiftIdActual,
    notes,
    status,
    ActualStartTime1,
    ActualEndTime1,
    ActualStartTime2,
    ActualEndTime2,
    TimeAttendanceId
)
select 754
   ,   A.workDate
   ,   6
   ,   0
   ,   0
   ,   0
   ,   0
   ,   0
   ,   0
   ,   0
   ,   0
   ,   10149
from   A
```

Some notes:

1. This hasn't been tested (SQLFiddle is giving me errors), so I can't guarantee it's correct as it stands.  However, I can help troubleshoot if you tell me (in comments) what's going wrong.
2. I am assuming you will ultimately want every day in the whole year, but if you want to restrict it to just Jan 1 to Nov 20, modify the `where` clause in the CTE.
3. If you need to restrict the dates to just M-F, you can probably add a `where` clause at the end to remove Saturdays and Sundays.